# htaccess error page file is not working with condition of rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have written a condition to auto add the path in the URL and it is working perfectly but now I want to add error pages but it is giving no response instead giving a 500 error.  **ErrorDocument** with text is working fine but it is not **adding file** I have already checked all possible paths but still no response.

This is my code in `.htaccess` file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /crud/views/pages/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
ErrorDocument 500 /404.html

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /crud/views/pages/$1 [L]
> ```

This will result in a rewrite loop (500 error) if you request a file (or directory) that does not exist when prefixed with `/crud/views/pages/`.

Note that defining the 500 `ErrorDocument` in `.htaccess` is too late for most 500 errors - this `ErrorDocument` would need to be defined *early* in the server config to catch this particular error.

You could resolve this rewrite-loop by first checking that the resource at the desired location exists before rewriting, instead of checking that the current request does not map to a file (or directory). This also involves just one filesystem check rather than two.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/crud/views/pages/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.*) crud/views/pages/$1 [L]
```

The first condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable just makes sure that only direct requests are check and not rewritten requests by the rule itself.